# CSS selector by inline style attribute while exclude an attribute value

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS selector to exclude 'display: none' from an element by its inline style attribute value? So i need to write a css selector where 'display: none' is not present.

```
<div style = "position: absolute; top: 12px; left: 84px; display: none;">
```

Looking for something like below:

```
div[not:style * = 'display: none']
```

OR

```
div:not[style*='display: none']
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close; you're just missing the parentheses for the [`not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector:

```css
div:not([style*='display: none']) {}
```

**Note**: This is space and case-sensitive. In other words, it will match this:

```html
<div style="display: none"></div>
```

and this:

```html
<div style="display:None"></div>
```

You can make it case insensitive by adding an `s` before the `]`, and space insensitive by adding another filter:

```css
div:not([style*='display: none' s]):not([style*='display:none' s]) {}
```